# Add Metadata to asset in Azure Media Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services, azure-api-apps

I am developing a background service with .Net, that will upload some videos to the azure media services platform and I would like to add some custom metadata to each video I will upload. I have google for some time, and I found that there is no possibility to upload an asset. [How to Add Metadata to assets in Azure Media Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103461/how-to-add-metadata-to-assets-in-azure-media-services) but having a look to the Azure dashboard I found, that selecting the properties of an asset I am able to add custom metadata manually. My question is, anybody have any idea how can I add this custom fields thougth through the azure media services API. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to add such metadata using Azure Storage APIs (and not via Media Services APIs). See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata) for example.

Comment: Correct, AMS is not meant to be a metadata management system. We recommend that you use the metadata feature on Azure Blobs via the Storage API if you want the metadata to move around with the blobs.  Or a more scalable solution would be to use Cosmos DB and insert a JSON document with all of your metadata, using the Asset ID or providing a custom "Alternate ID" on the Media Services Asset. 
We add the "Alternate ID" property to Asset in Media Services so that you could integrate a metadata database in that fashion.

Comment: Thanks Anil. Now i am able to request existing metadata and add new key pairs values. perfect!